# How to set up Mercurial username and email?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I am trying to set up my username and email address on Mercurial. The [tutorial](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialInstall) says:

> Mercurial will need a username to use for recording commits. It's best to configure Mercurial to use your email address by creating a file .hgrc in your home directory (or on Windows in %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini) containing lines like the following:
>
> ```
> [ui]
> username = John Doe <john@example.com>"
> ```

I found the "Mercurial" notepad file in the folder, not an ".ini" and The only thing that is written in that file is "# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog"

I did check other related questions and tried to find the answer. But, I really couldn't find. I want to use my bitbucket username and another email address on my commits. I am very new to coding and using version control systems. So, I hope I was able to explain the issue clearly.

Answer (score 4):

Is your Windows set to hide extensions for known file types? That would explain why you don't see `.ini` in Windows Explorer.
If you open it in Notepad, it should say "mercurial.ini - Notepad" in the title bar of Notepad if it's the correct file.

However, there you can do this through TortoiseHg. Open TortoiseHg Workbench, go to File -> Settings. In the Settings dialog, under the "*User*'s global settings" tab, select "Commit" in the left-hand list, and you'll see User name appear at the top of the pane to the right of the list. Type in your email address there and click OK. That should be it.

(But you could now check the file we discussed earlier and see if it has the relevant bits added to it)

Comment: Thank you. I did it using TortoiseHg. Now the username and email is added but I still don't see "ini" when I open it in Notepad.

Comment: This is a Windows setting, when viewing the file, go to the Tools -> Folder options menu (You may need to hit `Alt` to make the menu bar appear). In the view tab, in Advanced settings, there's an option `Hide extensions for known file types`. If that's checked, uncheck it and click ok.